# Apache multiple instances -- permission issues

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, permissions

I have a weird situation here...I have setup multiple Apache instances under debian:

1. The default install is left as is -- but disabled and stopped
2. A custom instance (apache2-apps)

The idea was to run each instance as distinct users -- default apache would be running third party apps (WordPress, Drupal, OpenCart, etc)

The second would be running our custom in house apps which work with highly proprietary data...

The idea/hope behind this setup was to isolate the apps from the web site software --without resorting to a VM (as I am already running in one) and slightly easier setup and secure? then Apache VirtualHost and/or PHP CGI

Anyhow...the problem I am encountering is the /var/www directory needs:

```
1. 755 permissions which make it readable by OTHER
 --- OR ----
2.I need to make www-data or www-apps an owner or group of this base directory.
```

My current file structure is as follows:

```
/var
  /www (user/group: webmin => RWXRWX--X)
    /applications (user/group: www-apps)
    /websites (user/group: www-data)
```

This setup would leave me to believe I could configure the default apache install to docroot the */var/www/websites* and apache2-apps docroot the */var/www/applications*

Each with a different user/group (**www-data** and **www-apps** respectively) thus isolating any security breach that may occur with public facing websites.

The problem I am running into is when I change the docroot of each apache instance to point to:

```
/var/www/applications
/var/www/websites
```

if I remove "other" read/exec permissions on /var/www so 770 -- apache gives me a "Forbidden 403" error when accessing the URI mapped to each docroot listed above. I am not sure I understand why...the docroot of each above have the 775 permissions

Can someone explain why I am encountering this issue? What am I failing to understand of how permissions work? Neither apache config is pointing to /var/www rather each instance points to it's respective directory one level deeper.

Alex

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing a directory, all higher directories require at least execute permission for that user (or group) as well, otherwise the application is not allowed to switch to that directory or directory below that.

Comment: Thanks for reply...sorry it's a Monday...so I am not fully understanding why :) As I understand it...I have two instances of Apache (neither point to the default /var/www). The docroot is /var/www/applications AND /var/www/websites -- so these directories should have the 770 permissions and group of www-data/www-apps -- why is this not sufficient?

Comment: OK I may have read what you said clearly enough...because appache is running under /var/www regardless of which user/group (www-data or www-apps) the "other" execution bit is still required on the /var/www?  I notice that most directories actually have the global X permission bit set...sorry for trivial questions...file permissions are something I still struggle with :)

Comment: Because you apparently run the daemons using different users, you have to make sure that both users have access to the underlying directory tree. It doesn't matter where your code lives, only the absolute path that the user you're running the daemon as tries to access. The x permission on the directory is enough to be able to access anything with more permissions below it.

Comment: OK I think I get it...I guess what still confuses me...if I gave /var/www/applications 750 permissions with owner/group: webmin/www-apps -- would this not be sufficient to avoid the X permission on /var/www?

Comment: No, each user that needs access to the subdirectories requires at least execute permission on the higher directories. I tried looking for a good example or better explanation online (only so much I can write in comments), but sadly couldn't find any. If you locked down the subdirectories however, any security impact from the execute permission is negligible (imho).

Comment: OK thanks for all your help...this setup isn't as secure as I thought it would be. I su'ed into www-apps from root and I could easily navigate outside the docroot into /etc/apache2-apps directory and even cat the darn file -- exposing passwords. So if someone managed to compromise the server or if I forgot to disable W permissions on a folder in the /var/www/applications - someone could write a new script and glob the whole FS viewing passwords stored in Apache configs...yikes...could I chroot the www-apps or www-data user to the intended docroot to prevent this?

Comment: Chroot and Apache is generally a bad mix, I believe. Maybe you should try virtualisation, something like Kvm or Docker even?

Comment: I'm already running in a VM...my admin is not interested in giving me another...and I am trying to get away from multiple servers...right now I maintain 3 physical servers...switching to one VM would make maintenance so much easier...our oldest webserver is running Debian Etch :O

Comment: Maybe need to explore PHPSuExec to prevent this secure issue from bring an issue :)

Comment: Then you should consider php-fpm. But this list of comments is getting way too long :)